Loading "tiled" open map with WMTS in Google Earth
How can I load in Google Earth a "tiled" open map with WMTS?
I was looking of an Open Source Map with high density contour level curves, and I found this MapServer website (ESRI World Topo Map):
https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer
but unfortunately, differently from other MapServer links I have used in the past, this one don't support WMS in order to load it in Google Earth as an Overlay layer.
But this MapServer do allow to make WMTS calls:

https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/WMTS?

But I don't know how to implement a tile map over Google Earth, neither I found useful information about this in Google.

Finally I tried also calling the map info as a Network Link, and as its web link I used the URL displayed on the link "ArcGIS Earth" from the MapServer website:
Network link: https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/kml/mapImage.kmz
And as a happy accident, it works!!!

It was impossible for me to do the same procedure with OpenTopoMap or OpenStreetMap. Fortunately an old link for the OpenStreetMap still works for making a Network Link in Google Earth, which allow to have 10 meters contour level lines:
Network link: http://mt.mgmaps.com/kml/maps.php
Can you explain how to make a Network link, or an Overlay layer with WMS, that allow to load in Google Earth nowadays maps like OpenStreetMap which are loaded natively as tiles map:

https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png

hopefully, without requiring an API Key.
